# How to manage multiple Cdn files and their CdnFallBackExpression?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, bundle, cdn

If I want to manage my Cdn file through the `bundleconfig.vb` file and load Kendo-ui from the Cdn, I need to create 2 bundles like this :

```
    Dim kendoWebBundle = New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendo", kendoCndWeb).Include("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.web.min.js")
    kendoWebBundle.CdnFallbackExpression = "typeof kendo"
    bundles.Add(kendoWebBundle)

    Dim kendoAspBundle = New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendoMvc", kendoCndAsp).Include("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")
    kendoAspBundle.CdnFallbackExpression = "typeof kendo"
    bundles.Add(kendoAspBundle)
```

However, my 2nd fallback expression won't work, since `kendo` will be defined :

#### output :

```
<script src="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
<script>(typeof kendo)||document.write('<script src="/Gabarit.Web/bundles/kendo"><\/script>');</script>

<script src="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
<script>(typeof kendo)||document.write('<script src="/Gabarit.Web/bundles/kendoMvc"><\/script>');</script>
```

Is there some `kendo.aspnetmvc` fallback expression or do I need to manage my Cdnfallback together (no fallbackExpression in bundleconfig, manually validate kendo type, if undefined, load all kendo files locally)?

If I go with the second option, what would happen if my CDN sends kendo.web.min.js, but not kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js? I feel kendo would be defined and no local fallback will happen...

Answer (score 2):

**Refer Kendo UI From CDN With a Local Script Fallback**

This is what [Telerik suggests](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/install/cdn#refer-kendo-ui-from-cdn-with-a-local-script-fallback) you should do.

Just test for a single script and if it fails load everything locally. So don't test for kendo.all.min.js, and then for kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js, if the CDN has issues you're probably not getting any of them.

```
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script>
    if (typeof kendo == "undefined") {
        // checking for loaded CSS files is cumbersome,
        // that's why we assume that if the scripts have failed, so have the stylesheets

        // fallback to local Kendo UI stylesheets
        document.write(decodeURIComponent('%3Clink rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/local/kendo.common.min.css" %3C/%3E'));
        document.write(decodeURIComponent('%3Clink rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/local/kendo.blueopal.min.css" %3C/%3E'));

        // fallback to local Kendo UI scripts
        document.write(decodeURIComponent('%3Cscript src="/path/to/local/kendo.all.min.js" %3E%3C/script%3E'));
        // also add kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js or kendo.timezones.min.js, if needed
    }
</script>
```

**ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework**

Like you're doing now, sorry for the C# below. Just put your Kendo UI scripts in separate bundles and specify the `typeof kendo == undefined` fallback expression.

Test CSS the same way, if the CDN doesn't provide the scripts then your CSS won't be there either.

Get the `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` package from NuGet. 
Now in your BundleConfig you can setup your bundles to include not only the CdnPath but also a CdnFallbackExpression:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{        
    bundles.UseCdn = true;
    var kendo = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts/kendo", "http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js").Include("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js");
    kendo.CdnFallbackExpression = "typeof kendo == undefined";
    bundles.Add(kendo);

    var kendoMvc = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts/kendoMvc", "http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js").Include("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js");
    kendoMvc.CdnFallbackExpression = "typeof kendo == undefined";
    bundles.Add(kendoMvc);      

    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```

Comment: But you can't put multiple files from a CDN in a bundle. :/ (Also, if I follow Telerik's advice, I just can't use the CdnFallBackExpression.)

Comment: Apologies for my half-assed answer earlier. I've done some proper testing  in my own project now and got a working solution (remember to update it with your own paths). I'm not sure why the fallback wouldn't work for you though?

Comment: It "works", but look at my output (in the question) and consider that the cdn is down. It will first try to load kendo.web from the cdn and fails. Then it will loads locally. After that it will try to load kendo.aspnetmvc from the cdn and fails. Then it won't load locally because the fallback expression is the same, aka, 'kendo' is now defined.

Comment: You only need a fallback if the CDN is down. If you can load kendo,all, then kendo.mvc will come as well. Telerik also says this in their post. There is no need to check each file.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the fallback expression to "kendo" will cause the local resource to be used.

I've modified @Nicholas code to reflect that:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{        
    bundles.UseCdn = true;
    var kendo = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts/kendo", "http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js").Include("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js");
    kendo.CdnFallbackExpression = "kendo";
    bundles.Add(kendo);

    var kendoMvc = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts/kendoMvc", "http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js").Include("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js");
    kendoMvc.CdnFallbackExpression = "kendo";
    bundles.Add(kendoMvc);      

    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```